# Some items in enumerate jump left out of margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, indentation, itemize, parbox

I have a boxed list in latex, and for some reason some items jump out of the box out of the left margin. I cannot figure out what is causing this and already have searched and tried some fixes. The code:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{The Lin-Kernighan Modified Distance Algorithm}
    \label{fig:LKMD}
    \noindent

    \fbox{
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
            {\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont
\begin{spacing}{1}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Initialise the algorithm
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Calculate for every item $s_i = \frac{p_i}{w_i}$ and rank them based on the score.
            \item Pick items starting from the highest rank until the knapsack is full.
            \item Set LB = 0\%.
            \item Set UB = 20\%.
            \item Set \epsilon = 0.1.
            \item Set $Z^* = -inf$, the best improvement found so far.
        \end{enumerate} 
    \item While UB - LB > \epsilon:
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item for C \in \{UB, LB\}
            \item Modify the distance matrix:
                  $d'_{ij}$=\left\{
                        \begin{array}{ll}
                                        $(1 - C) \cdot d_{ij} \text{ if } i \in N_h \text{ and } j \in N_1$\\
                                        $(1 - C) \cdot d_{ij} \text{ if } i \in N_1 \text{ and } j \in N_1$\\
                                       $ (1 + C) \cdot d_{ij} \text{ if } i \in N_1 \text{ and } j \in N_0$\\
                                        $(1 + C) \cdot d_{ij} \text{ if } i \in N_0 \text{ and } j \in N_1$\\
                                        $d_{ij} \text{ else }$ \\
                        \end{array}
                        \right.
                \item Run LK algorithm with modified distances and evaluate the objective function (OBJ) for LB and UB
                \item
        \end{enumerate} 
\end{itemize}
\end{spacing}
}
}
}
\end{figure}
```

I also notice it is coming out weird here as qwll, but I don't know why...

I included a picture of the print out.

[image: output]

Comment: You must use math mode if you want to write math

Comment: You tell the array to have two columns, yet you don't have any column sperators

Comment: Thanks, this indeed fixed it... oops

Answer (score 1):

two problems:

- You must use math mode if you want to write math
- You tell the array to have two columns, yet you don't have any column separators

or summary:

- you must not ignore error messages

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{The Lin-Kernighan Modified Distance Algorithm}
    \label{fig:LKMD}
    \noindent

    \fbox{
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
            {\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont
\begin{spacing}{1}
\begin{itemize}


    \item Initialise the algorithm

        \begin{enumerate}

            \item Calculate for every item $s_i = \frac{p_i}{w_i}$ and rank them based on the score.

            \item Pick items starting from the highest rank until the knapsack is full.

            \item Set $LB = 0\%$.

            \item Set $UB = 20\%$.

            \item Set $\epsilon = 0.1$.

            \item Set $Z^* = -inf$, the best improvement found so far.

        \end{enumerate} 

    \item While $UB - LB > \epsilon$:

        \begin{enumerate}
            \item for $C \in \{UB, LB\}$

            \item Modify the distance matrix:
                  \[d'_{ij}=\left\{
                        \begin{array}{ll}
                                        (1 - C) \cdot d_{ij} &\text{ if } i \in N_h \text{ and } j \in N_1\\
                                        (1 - C) \cdot d_{ij} &\text{ if } i \in N_1 \text{ and } j \in N_1\\
                                        (1 + C) \cdot d_{ij} &\text{ if } i \in N_1 \text{ and } j \in N_0\\
                                        (1 + C) \cdot d_{ij} &\text{ if } i \in N_0 \text{ and } j \in N_1\\
                                        d_{ij} &\text{ else } \\
                        \end{array}
                        \right.\]

                \item Run LK algorithm with modified distances and evaluate the objective function (OBJ) for LB and UB

                \item
        \end{enumerate} 
\end{itemize}
\end{spacing}
}
}
}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Stupid I didn't notice...

Answer (score 1):

Some improvements, with `caption`, `enumitem` and `mathtools` and the `cases` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \caption{The Lin-Kernighan Modified Distance Algorithm}
    \label{fig:LKMD}
    \noindent

    \fbox{
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
            {\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont
\begin{spacing}{1}
\begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]

    \item Initialise the algorithm

        \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]

            \item Calculate for every item $s_i = \frac{p_i}{w_i}$ and rank them based on the score.

            \item Pick items starting from the highest rank until the knapsack is full.

            \item Set $LB = 0\%$.

            \item Set $UB = 20\%$.

            \item Set $\epsilon = 0.1$.

            \item Set $Z^* = -inf$, the best improvement found so far.

        \end{enumerate}

    \item While $UB - LB > \epsilon$:

        \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]
            \item for $C \in \{UB, LB\}$

  \item Modify the distance matrix:
 \[ d'_{ij}=
 \begin{cases*}
 (1 - C) \cdot d_{ij} & if $ i \in N_h $ and $ j \in N_1 $ \\
 (1 - C) \cdot d_{ij} & if $ i \in N_1 $ and $ j \in N_1 $ \\
 (1 + C) \cdot d_{ij} & if $ i \in N_1 $ and $ j \in N_0 $ \\
 d_{ij} & otherwise
 \end{cases*}
 \]

                \item Run LK algorithm with modified distances and evaluate the objective function (OBJ) for LB and UB

                \item
        \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{spacing}
}}}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]